# Copy DataFrame to clipboard

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I am new to JS development and am trying to build an 'extension' that copies data from Tableau to clipboard. I am calling an API that returns data on click as a dataframe. I have managed to get the data mapped to the console using console.log but I can't make it copy to the clipboard (see my js below). Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Code is below:

```js
function copyRows() {
//THIS IS THE API CALL TO CREATE THE DATAFRAME WHICH HOLDS DATA CALLED//  
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textarea.value =   
    
    tableau.extensions.initializeAsync().then(() => {
  let dashboard = tableau.extensions.dashboardContent.dashboard;
  let worksheet = dashboard.worksheets.find(w => w.name === 'Orders');
  worksheet.getSummaryDataAsync().then(dataTable => {
    let field = dataTable.columns.find(column => column.fieldName === 'Order ID');
    let values = [];
    for (let row of dataTable.data) {
        values.push(row[field.index].value);
    };

//THE DATA CAN BE MAPPED TO THE CONSOLE//    
  console.log(values)

//BUT USING THE BELOW I CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW TO GET THE DATAFRAME COPIED TO CLIPBOARD//
  document.body.appendChild(values);
  values.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(values);
        });
    });
};
```